# Using stock management of Odoo with Open ERP

Tags: api, odoo, rpc, erp

I have an MVC application with one part of it deals with Stock/Store management.  Odoo has a good stock management module, which if integrated with my application would handle the stock part of the software.

The application is developed with MVC, c# and the backend SQL server.

How can I integrate Odoo stock module with my application? I want to access (read and write) just the stock module through an api (RPC).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK only way you can achieve this is by running an instance of Odoo with its own postgresql database and all the modules on which stock module depends on installed.

Then you should use [RPC](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html) to call not just stock module, but also other modules, such as product, in order to fill database with your products. Basically you will have to replicate a large part of your data over Odoo database.

You need to ask yourself if it's worth the trouble, maybe it would be faster (both in developing and in performance) to just replicate Odoo's stock management inside your own MVC.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro - Is there a way to know the list of services / methods, so that to call them from a client application? I found 'system.listMethods' but all in Python.

Comment: I don't think so. In your rpc request you write the name of the model and the method you want to call. Search for methods into models definitions